# Adding a new column based on other row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with various types of nuts as well as where the were sold, and how many were sold. I would like to append the price to the dataframe based on the nut type, but I haven't found any answers that seem to help with this. I currently have:

```
nuts = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Classes\INFO 4120\Stat L3 HW\STATL3Nuts.csv', index_col=0)
```

`nuts.head()`

```
    Quantity    Location    Type
   0    5         Parker    Pistachio
   1    8         Parker    Pistachio
   2    6         Parker    Pistachio
   3    4         Parker    Pistachio
   4    2         Parker    Pistachio
```

and a dataframe of the prices:

```
pricedf = pd.DataFrame({'Type':[10.5,8.75,9.25]},index=['Pistachio','Walnut','Cashew'])
pricedf
             Type
Pistachio   10.50
Walnut       8.75
Cashew       9.25
```

This might be remedial, but I am really struggling. I would like the end result to be something close to:

```
        Quantity    Location    Type    Price
   0    5         Parker    Pistachio    10.5
   1    8         Parker    Pistachio    10.5
   2    6         Parker    Pistachio    10.5
   3    4         Parker    Pistachio    10.5
   4    2         Parker    Cashew       9.25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map`, using the `pricedf` column `Price` as a mapping series:

```
nuts['Price'] = nuts['Type'].map(pricedf['Type'])
```

Comment: I swear that I tried that before, but I must have had the syntax wrong. Thank you so much.